# Redirecting email traffic using iptables or rinetd isn't working but http traffic is

Tags: email, iptables, redirect, nat

Initial situation:
I had a shared cpanel hosting account (website + email).
Let's call it mydomain.com with ip: a.b.c.d

The DNS RECORDS were like so:

```
mydomain.com A a.b.c.d
mail.mydomain.com A a.b.c.d

mydomain.com MX 0:mydomain.com
mail.mydomain.com MX 10:mydomain.com
```

Everything worked fine.

We then rebuilt our website in python and hosted it on DigitalOcean ( IP: e.f.g.h ) and updated the DNS RECORDS like so:

```
mydomain.com A e.f.g.h
mail.mydomain.com A a.b.c.d

mydomain.com MX 0:mail.mydomain.com
mail.mydomain.com MX 10:mail.mydomain.com
```

Now email was working only with the mail.mydomain.com domain and for technical reasons (hundreds of printers that are sending monthly page index already configured to send emails using mydomain.com (not mail.mydomain.com) so we absolutely needed to have mydomain.com working too ).

For that we've used iptables to forward email traffic from the digitalocean droplet to the cpanel server using these rules (ports: 110, 143, 993, 25, 465, 587):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <port> -j DNAT --to-destination a.b.c.d:<port>
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport <port> -j MASQUERADE


/etc/sysctl.conf:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 # is enabled
```

Now everything worked fine until the droplet restarted yesterday because I didn't know iptables settings aren't persistent and I had to save them.

Now I tried to use the same settings and the redirecting isn't working anymore. I tried flushing iptables and adding the rules again. I've used multiple email clients and the email is working fine if I use mail.mydomain.com but saying settings are not correct if using mydomain.com as a mail server.

Then I cleared all iptables settings using:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

and installed rinetd. This is my rinetd config file:

```
# bindadress    bindport  connectaddress  connectport
# SMTP
0.0.0.0         25        a.b.c.d   25
# Secure SMTP
0.0.0.0         465        a.b.c.d   465
# POP3
0.0.0.0        110        a.b.c.d  110
# IMAP
0.0.0.0        143        a.b.c.d  143
# STARSSL
0.0.0.0        587        a.b.c.d  587
# IMAP over TLS
0.0.0.0        993        a.b.c.d  993
# POP3 over TLS
0.0.0.0        995        a.b.c.d  995
```

and this is the log when I try to connect an email with thunderbird:

```
25/Apr/2020:08:14:30    x.x.x.x 0.0.0.0 993 a.b.c.d 993 0   0   opened
25/Apr/2020:08:14:37    x.x.x.x 0.0.0.0 143 a.b.c.d 143 0   0   opened
25/Apr/2020:08:14:37    x.x.x.x 0.0.0.0 143 a.b.c.d 143 0   0   opened
25/Apr/2020:08:14:37    x.x.x.x 0.0.0.0 587 a.b.c.d 587 0   0   opened
25/Apr/2020:08:14:37    x.x.x.x 0.0.0.0 25  a.b.c.d 25  0   0   opened
25/Apr/2020:08:14:37    x.x.x.x 0.0.0.0 587 a.b.c.d 587 0   0   opened
25/Apr/2020:08:14:37    x.x.x.x 0.0.0.0 25  a.b.c.d 25  0   0   opened
```

Thunderbird still is saying it couldn't find any settings.

I then tried to redirect http traffic on port 80 to another website using rinetd and it works fine so rinetd is working. Only email traffic gets stuck somewhere I think.

EDIT: SOLVED, thanks for the help. The forwarding worked but the CPANEL hosting company blacklisted my ip(e.f.g.h) due to too much traffic. They whitelisted it now.

Comment: Are you sure those MX records are valid? I've never seen a zone in that format be for (if they are not valid, that would explain it - there would be a fallback to the A record)

Comment: it's short for priority:destination.

Comment: I understand what its trying to say, but I've not seen a name server use a : to separate the priority from the record. Have you run any external checks to validate it?

Comment: @davidgo solved the hosting company blacklisted my ip. Thanks for the help.